# Paths and subpath don't manage the arc curve the same way

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm having issue with generating arc curves with Raphael.

I created a reduced example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxilart/m6cHw/3/

As you can see, the first path drawn isn't the same as the second one, and the second one is only a subpath of the first.

Do you know why both are different? And how could I resolve this issue?

Here's the code:

```
function drawpath( canvas, bg, pathstr, duration, attr, callback ) {
    var guide_path = bg;
    var path = canvas.path( guide_path.getSubpath( 0, 1 ) ).attr( attr );
    var total_length = guide_path.getTotalLength( guide_path );
    var last_point = guide_path.getPointAtLength( 0 );
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var interval_length = 50;
    var result = path;

    var run = function run() {
        var elapsed_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
        var this_length = elapsed_time / duration * total_length;
        var subpathstr = guide_path.getSubpath( 0, this_length );

        path.attr({ path: subpathstr });

        if ( elapsed_time >= duration ) {
            if ( callback != undefined ) callback();
        } else {
            requestAnimationFrame(run);
        }
    };
    run();
    return result;
}

var sequence_path = [
    [ "M", 200, 0 ],
    [ "V", 200 ],
    [ "A", 100, 100, 90, 0, 0, 300, 300 ],
    [ "H", 400 ],
    [ "A", 100, -100, 90, 0, 0, 500, 400 ],
    [ "V", 500 ],
    [ "A", 100, -100, 90, 0, 0, 400, 600 ],
    [ "H", 200 ],
    [ "A", 100, 100, 90, 0, 0, 100, 700 ],
    [ "V", 800 ]
];

var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 700, 1000);

var bg = paper.path(sequence_path).attr({
    stroke: 'white',
    'stroke-width': 64,
    'stroke-opacity': 1,
    fill: 'none',
    'fill-opacity': 0
});

drawpath( paper, bg, sequence_path, 3500, {
    stroke: 'orange',
    'stroke-width': 64,
    'stroke-opacity': 1,
    fill: 'none',
    'fill-opacity': 0
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Raphael's getSubpath method has a bug where it misinterprets the Large Arc Flags and Sweep Flags of a couple of those curves. I might be wrong.

Edit: OK I was wrong. You have some bad Arcs (A) that are breaking something somewhere between Raphael and the browser, not sure where. But the problem is:

You are setting negative y-radius on the two Arcs that get messed up. Radius cant be negative. in your `sequence_path` definition, change those two `-100`'s to `100` (positive 100 y radius). updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6cHw/4/

If you're going to be hand-writing a lot of paths, I suggest you read the standards specs on how to define them: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html. I tried to avoid reading that for a while but eventually I bit the bullet and went through it. It's weird stuff but you need to understand it if you want to make paths do what you want.